# Changing the direction of a Flexbox HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox with 4 images. Below is an image of what it looks like now. Currently, when I make the width smaller, you don't see the 4th image.
[image]

I want the flexbox to transform into this layout below. So that when the width is at a certain px, it will change.

[image]

I'm having trouble accomplishing this. I tried to use flex-direction: column; but this makes the whole list vertical and I don't want that.

```css
div{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: wrap;
  border-style:solid;
  padding-top: 2em;
}

figcaption[certification=yes]::before {
            font-size: 0.75em;
            /*Check mark*/
            content: "\2705";
            display: inline-block;
            color:red;
}

figcaption[certification=yes]::after {
            font-size: 0.75em;
            /*Dispaly li*/
            content: li;
            display: inline-block;
            color:red;
}

figure{
    padding:2.5em;
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-bottom:2em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1185px)
{
    // I want the 4th image to below the 1st image once you get to the width of 1185px
    div{ 
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/ACE.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure>
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/NSCA.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure>
   
        <figure>
            <img src="images/USA.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure> 
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/Functional-movement.jpg" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `flex-direction:wrap;`

Try instead: `flex-wrap:wrap;`

Also, instead of using `em` units (or px or rem), use instead `vw` and `vh` "view units". These units represent 1% of the current screen width and height (and you can use fractions of units, so they become infinitely more granular - e.g. `1.25vw`), so the margin/borders/padding/etc will also grow/shrink with the screen size. *How do view units differ from percents? Percents relate to the percentages of the parent div size, whereas view units are percentages of the current viewport size.*

References:

https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#flex-wrap

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/05/fluid-typography/

---

#### Demo:

```css
div{display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;border-style:solid;padding-top:2em;}

figcaption[certification=yes]::before{font-size:0.75em;/*Check mark*/content:"\2705";display:inline-block;color:red;}
figcaption[certification=yes]::after{font-size:0.75em;/*Dispaly li*/content:li;display:inline-block;color:red;}
figure{padding:2.5em;margin-left:3em;margin-bottom:2em;}

@media screen and (max-width:1185px)
{// I want the 4th image to below the 1st image once you get to the width of 1185px
    div{flex-wrap:wrap;}
}
```

```html
<div>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/ACE.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure>
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/NSCA.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure>
   
        <figure>
            <img src="images/USA.png" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure> 
  
        <figure>
            <img src="images/Functional-movement.jpg" height="150em">
            <figcaption data-title="Multimedia and the World Wide Web" certification="yes">Nighthawk</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
```